# Failed to call APIs from web page behind Azure APIM due to CORS issues

Tags: azure, cors

I am using Azure APIM , my APIs are hosted on Azure app service coded by .net core . I have configed my apis behind APIM . However , when I tried to call my APIs , I got this issue :

> Access to fetch at '' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is the js code that I call my API :

```
var url='<the url of my api in APIM>';
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Seckey":"xxxxxx"
    },
    body: '<some json content>'
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log("Response succeeded?", JSON.stringify(res.status));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("fetch fail", JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

I know this is a CORS issue , and I have configed CORS policy in APIM based on this doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies#CORS

However, it did not solve this issue . So did I miss something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Thiago Custodio said, you should config CROS in both of your Azure app services and APIM.

Btw,if you have enabled CROS for your Azure app service ,  pls check you have configed CORS correctly in your APIM, based on your request, I noticed that you have a custom header : `Seckey`, have you configed it in your CORS policy?

If not , pls try the CORS policy below, or you will meet CORS issue:

```
<cors >
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>http://localhost:8080/</origin> 
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
        <method>POST</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>Content-Type</header>
        <header>Seckey</header>
    </allowed-headers>
</cors>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Where have you placed your policy? CORS will only work at the API and Operation level and **not the product level**.
See this blog for the scope of the policy in APIM.
https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/12/28/policy-scope-in-azure-api-management/

This is an extract from an example of Azure APIM CORS policy that works.

```
      <inbound>
            </base>
            <cors allow-credentials="true">
                <allowed-origins>
                    <origin>http://localhost/</origin>
                </allowed-origins>
                <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
                    <method>GET</method>
                    <method>POST</method>
                </allowed-methods>
                <allowed-headers>
                    <header>Authorization</header>
                    <header>Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key</header>
                    <header>content-type</header>
                </allowed-headers>
            </cors>
        </inbound>
        
        <outbound>
            <base />
            
            <!--CORS-->
            <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" exists-action="override">
                <value>true</value>
            </set-header>
    
            <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" exists-action="override">
                <value>*</value>
            </set-header>
        </outbound>
```

Some documents suggest to add this header in the outbound too.

```
    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
                    <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Origin",""))</value>
                </set-header>
```